module 'numpy' has no attribute 'float'
I would like to apply a trained model on pointclouds for inference task (https://github.com/zhulf0804/PointPillars) using ROS2 (humble). I found this GitHub repo in this regard(https://github.com/ragibarnab/ros2-lidar-object-detection/tree/master). ROS2 environment was installed withpython 3.10.12 and numpy 1.26.4. I have successfully built the package (colcon build). However, when I use ros2 run lidar_object_detection lidar_publisher_node, I get this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/abbas/ros2_pointpillars/install/lidar_object_detection/lib/lidar_object_detection/lidar_publisher_node", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('lidar-object-detection==0.0.0', 'console_scripts', 'lidar_publisher_node')())
  File "/home/abbas/ros2_pointpillars/install/lidar_object_detection/lib/lidar_object_detection/lidar_publisher_node", line 25, in importlib_load_entry_point
    return next(matches).load()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/metadata/__init__.py", line 171, in load
    module = import_module(match.group('module'))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/abbas/ros2_pointpillars/install/lidar_object_detection/lib/python3.10/site-packages/lidar_object_detection/lidar_publisher_node.py", line 3, in <module>
    import ros2_numpy as rnp
  File "/home/abbas/ros2_pointpillars/install/ros2_numpy/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ros2_numpy/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from . import geometry
  File "/home/abbas/ros2_pointpillars/install/ros2_numpy/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ros2_numpy/geometry.py", line 3, in <module>
    import tf_transformations as transformations
  File "/opt/ros/humble/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tf_transformations/__init__.py", line 47, in <module>
    import transforms3d
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/transforms3d/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from . import quaternions
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/transforms3d/quaternions.py", line 26, in <module>
    _MAX_FLOAT = np.maximum_sctype(np.float)
  File "/home/abbas/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 324, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(__former_attrs__[attr])
AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'float'.
`np.float` was a deprecated alias for the builtin `float`. To avoid this error in existing code, use `float` by itself. Doing this will not modify any behavior and is safe. If you specifically wanted the numpy scalar type, use `np.float64` here.
The aliases was originally deprecated in NumPy 1.20; for more details and guidance see the original release note at:
    https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/1.20.0-notes.html#deprecations. Did you mean: 'cfloat'?
[ros2run]: Process exited with failure 1

It seems np.float was a deprecated alias for the installed numpy version.
I have also tried this with anaconda: 1) activate an anaconda environment (python 3.7.16, numpy 1.19.5) , 2) source /opt/ros/humble/setup.bash, 3) cd to ROS2 package, 4) source install/setup.bash, and 5) ros2 run lidar_object_detection lidar_publisher_node. But, I still get the same error even with numpy<1.20.
How can I solve this issue?
I appreciate any help in advance.

Can you update or modify this transforms3d/quaternions.py module?

@hpaulj  Thank you for your prompt reply. I tried to modify the code, but it seems I can not edit, delete, rename, or replace it. Any idea how to modify the file?

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/75064958/674039

Your transforms3d appears to be out of date. This issue is fixed in more recent releases.

@wim Thank you for your suggestion. I tried to modify np.float in quaternions.py, but it seems I can not edit, delete, rename, or replace it. Any idea how to modify the file?

@user2357112 Thank you for your response. I have installed transforms3d 0.4.1 for a conda environment. Then, source ROS2 package and run the publisher. But, I still get the same error.
